# Is my HP DeskJest 1512 All-In-One printer compatible with Ubuntu 14.04? How do I install it if it is?

Tags: printing

I was given an HP DeskJet 1512 All-In-One printer as a graduation gift. I have also recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP Probook 4510s with a 32-bit 1Gb RAM and a Celeron processor. I am still adjusting to the change from Windows Vista. Is the printer compatible and if so how can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to almost all of your printing troubles if you include **cups**, Common Unix Printing System) in your queries.

If you look at [the cups feature summary for your model](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_1510_series.html), you will find that it supports all the major features with the *hplip* package.  Your DeskJet will work pretty much out of the box.

You find the cups administration interface in your web browser at localhost:631. (The form here does not allow linking to localhost).

A nice troubleshooting guide is set up by the good folks at [ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems).  I recently used the `tail -f /var/log/syslog` command when plugging in a finicky HP printer, only to find the solution to my problem written verbatim in that output.

NoviceUserFrance was nice to add that SimpleScan is a very easy to use scanning tool for your scanning needs.

Comment: And, if you add SimpleScan from the Ubuntu Software Centre, you will also get a fabulous scanning utility to utilise the very best of your new acquisition.